# ActiveRecord finding "best effort" results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a bunch of users who are stored in a Redis scoreboard style thing. But, sometimes those users get deleted, and they don't get deleted in Redis. This is non crucial for my app, so I don't mind. However, Rails, when trying to get the results using a query like so:

```
User.find([1,2,3,4,244])
```

Rails can't find one of the users so it returns this really helpful error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Users with IDs (1, 2, 3, 4, 244) (found 4 results, but was looking for 5)
```

(Kudos to rails for human readable errors!)

I'm wondering though, is there a way to do a best effort find to get all the results that exist in that array, and not care if all the results aren't returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `where` instead, you'll be good:

```
User.where(id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 244])
```

Rails will translate this to `"id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 244)` in SQL, which is exactly the same sql as your `find` statement would execute, but Rails will not require the exact number of records be returned using `where`, unlike `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SQL` `in` command. This will return all existing values on your database and ignore the others.

```
User.where('id in ?', [1,2,3,4,244])
User.where(id => [1, 2, 3, 4, 244])
```